# Is this conditional check overkill?

Tags: php

$result = validateUploadedFile($_FILES);

```
if (!empty($result) && !empty($result['valid']) && $result['valid'])
{
    // do sth
    // I don't know why sometime this three checks will cause me problems
    // In other words, even if $result['valid'] is TRUE, this scope will not be hit
}
```

The function validateUploadedFile returns an array as $result['valid'] == TRUE if it goes through.

Here is the question, does the if statement checks too much?
Can I simply check the following instead? I have few PHP language knowledge and don't know whether those checks are necessary or not.

```
if ( $result['valid'] )
{
    // do sth
}
```

Thank you

```
function validateUploadedFile($uploadedFile)
{
    // Define file size limit
    $result = array('valid' => FALSE, 'error_message' => null, 'error_code' => null);

    if (sth_wrong)
    {
      $result['error_message'] = 'sth_wrong';
      return $result;    
    }

    if (sth_wrong2)
    {
      $result['error_message'] = 'sth_wrong2';
      return $result;    
    }    

    $result['valid'] = TRUE;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What does validateUploadedFile look like? Will it always have a valid? If you are through in the function then you have the luxury of being less careful with the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what the function returns in the case where the uploaded file is not valid. This should probably suffice in most cases though:

```
if (!empty($result['valid']))
```

Since:

- `FALSE` is `empty`
- `NULL` (or an unset array index) is `empty`
- It won't complain, even if `$result` is an empty array

You could also just do

```
if (!$result['valid'])
```

but this will give you `E_NOTICE` if that element isn't set.

Comment: This is correct. Check whether $result has a value, optionally also that it is an array, and then check whether the key of the array has a value.

Comment: Hello Ramon,

I just found in some cases, I just CANNOT get the expected results if I check the three conditions in a row.

It seems that !empty is best for me.
Does !empty give me a E_NOTICE?

thank you

Comment: No, it does not. Even if `$result` is completely undefined which is something to watch out for since there is the danger of mistyping something like `empty($reslut['valid'])` for which you will get no error message.

Answer (score 4):

I would think

```
if (isset($result['valid']) && $result['valid'])
```

would work just fine.

Comment: Hello Zahymaka,

I read somewhere that indicates !empty is better than isset.

thank you

Comment: !empty should work without throwing an E_NOTICE error as long as the 'valid' index is set.

Comment: I think `empty` is like `isset` in that it doesn't require the argument to exist so no `E_NOTICE` error should occur even if `valid` index is not set at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is more of what you should be doing with raw user input. Since you're dealing with a function, however, it would be a lot easier to have it do the heavy lifting.

Just ensure it always sets the `'valid'` key; your code will be more readable and secure. If you do that, an `if($result['valid'])` will suffice.

Comment: According to the update, in this case the `'valid'` key is always set, so `if($result['valid'])` will indeed suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it. In this particular case, it seems you're not entirely sure which values to check for. In most cases and according to logic, simply doing a !$result['valid'] /should/ work - but that's assuming PHP considers null / unset values as 'false'.

Make a quick script that tests all the conditions separately.

- What happens when calling empty($result['valid']) when $result is null?
- What happens when calling !$result['valid'] when $result['valid'] is undefined?

Go on. Write a script. Test it, and Know.

Comment: Hello Cthulhu,

I have found problems that I cannot make 3 checks in a roll. I will have some problems for some results.

Thank you